# Convert HTML table row to object without HTML tags

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-web-api

I have a table populated from a Webapi call. I'm allowing a person to make changes to the section via selector. What i need to do is get the name of the section, the "add level", "edit Level", "Delete Level" and "read Level" for each row.
What i had planned to do was SerializeArray() to get the value pairs(name / value) which does work, except that i have to add a differentiation to the names (add, inquire, edit, etc) to identify which goes where
What I currently have

**HTML:**

```html
<form id="InventoryFrm" >
  <table id="InventoryTable">
    <thead>
      <tr id="Columns"> 
        <th> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> Inventory</th>
        <th>Add Level</th>
        <th>Edit Level</th>
        <th>Delete Level</th>
        <th>Inquire Level</th>
        <th>Last Updated</th>
        <th>Updated By</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="InventoryTableBody" >

    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var InventoryBody = $('.InventoryTableBody');
 $.each(res.Inventory, function(index,value){
 $.each(value, function(id, val){ 
InventoryBody.append(` <tr><td>${value[id].EntityName}</td>
<td><select id="${value[id].EntityName}add"> <option>${value[id].AddLevel[0]}</option><option>${value[id].AddLevel[1]}</option><option>${value[id].AddLevel[2]}</option></select></td>  
 <td> <select id="${value[id].EntityName}edit"> <option>${value[id].EditLevel[0]}</option><option>${value[id].EditLevel[1]}</option><option>${value[id].EditLevel[2]}</option></select></td>  
 <td> <select id="${value[id].EntityName}delete"> <option>${value[id].DeleteLevel[0]}</option><option>${value[id].DeleteLevel[1]}</option><option>${value[id].DeleteLevel[2]}</option></select></td>
<td> <select id="${value[id].EntityName}inquire"> <option>${value[id].InquireLevel[0]}</option><option>${value[id].InquireLevel[1]}</option><option>${value[id].InquireLevel[2]}</option></select></td>
                    <td></td><td></td> </tr>`);
                  })
                })


var InvFm=$("#InventoryFrm").serializeArray();
```

Which gives me an object like so

```js
{name: "Items add", value: "All"}
{name: "Items edit", value: "All"}
{name: "Items delete", value: "All"}
{name: "Items inquire", value: "All"}
```

This is technically all one row for "Items" and should be something like

```
Name: "Items" Add: "All" Edit: "All" Delete: "All" Inquire: "All"
```

The idea is that it is dynamic so someone can change it as needed so Items isn't "hard-coded" in either.
If i get the TR i have to deal with the HTML  which means even more unnecessary data to weed out.
Is there a better way that i'm missing/overthinking to get the Relevant Data from the Row or am i stuck converting

Answer (score 0):

If the format will always be: `{name: "OBJECT ACTION", value: "VALUE"}`, then your process is pretty simple.

- Get row one.
- Explode name by space. That gives you "OBJECT".
- Iterative over each row.
- Explode name by space. That gives you "ACTION".
- Grab value. That gives you "VALUE.

At that point, you're just reformatting the data as needed.

---

*Update Based On Comment*

If some of your objects haves spaces in them, all may not be lost. If your actions *don't* have spaces in them, you can use a regex statement to query all but the action.

Comment: Some of the object names have spaces in them so breaking at spaces is unreliable. But I was hoping to avoid iterating over each row.